# Uncaught ReferenceError: onload_functions is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript

Hi i am having a problem getting some small javascript to work it works on phpbb 3.0.12 but fails on the new 3.1.1
The error is Uncaught ReferenceError: onload_functions is not defined (anonymous function)

the call

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var colour_mark_forums = '{U_MARK_FORUMS}';
onload_functions[onload_functions.length] = 'colour_parse_forums();';
// ]]>
</script>
```

the javascript

```js
function colour_parse_forums()
{
    var is_new;
    // find all categories
    $('div.forabg').each(function(i) 
    {
        if($('li.row-new', this).length > 0)
        {
            $(this).addClass('block-new');
        }
    });
    // find all forums
    if(colour_mark_forums && colour_mark_forums.indexOf("&amp;mark=forums") > 0);
    {
        $('li.row-new').dblclick(function()
        {
            colour_mark_read(this.id);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it [changed in 3.1](https://wiki.phpbb.com/PhpBB3.1#JavaScript_onload_functions_changed) and you need to be pushing a function reference rather than a string now

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.phpbb.com/PhpBB3.1#Moving_from_3.0_to_3.1

```
onload_functions.push(colour_parse_forums);
```